# apache2: VirtualHost configuration for application and repository

Tags: centos, virtualhost, redirection

I use apache2 2.2 on CentOs 2.6.

I need to configure my apache2 to allow me to use my wildfly application and source code repository.
For my application I use address: domain.com and it will redirect me to my app:  localhost:8080/app1   .
Using link domain.com/repos/app1 I want to be able to use my source code repository (localhost/repos/app1). Both links use port 80.

With following configuration I am able to use my application but cannot access my repository because request to it is redirected to my wildfly app1 and of course "there is no such page" page is shown there.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain.com
   ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app1/
   ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8080/app1/

   RewriteEngine   On
   RewriteCond     %{THE_REQUEST}  /app1/
   RewriteRule     ^/app1/(.*)$ /$1 [PT]

</VirtualHost>
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: why are you using proxy ? why are you rewriting the url ? why don't you have DocumentRoots ?

Comment: This is a production server. The world cannot see port 8080 but only 80. Jboss/wildfly cannot use port 80 because only applications run by root user can use ports below 1000.  It has to be root domain ("/") as a start point. I don't use apache2's directories at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your correctly, you want to access both a local folder and an app running on an app server from 2 URLS.
If you ProxyPass / then when you'll try to access domain.com/repos it will be proxied to your wildfly app.
domain.com/repos -> (wildfly) http://localhost:8080/app1/repos

You should use domain.com/app1 to reach your app and then domain.com/repos to reach your repo. Then you don't need the URL

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1/
ProxyPassReverse /app1  http://localhost:8080/app1/
```

Comment: localhost/repos/app1 is an URL indicated by SVN server, it is not a physical local folder. This is repository server, not wildfly application server. If I ProxyPass / then I want to be proxied to domain.com:8080/app1. If I proxyPass /repos/app1 I want to reach localhost/repos/app1.   I have to use "/" for my main wildfly application because I cannot tell them to use domain.com:8080/app1 (this looks strange...)

Comment: Okay, you didn't make it so clear that /repos wasn't a physical local folder.
So I guess you can do (keep the order)
`ProxyPass /repos/app1 http://your-repo-server/`
`ProxyPassReverse /repos/app1  http://your-repo-server/`

`ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app1/`
`ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8080/app1/`

Comment: Without VirtualHost configuration I can access my repository using domain.com/repos/app1 . If I have my VirtualHost configuration and I want to go to: domain.com/repos/app1 then I am redirected to domain.com/app1. Maybe the problem is with RewriteCond? And my-repo-server is localhost/repos/app1.